# Is there a race condition when creating unique paths?

Tags: neo4j

I recently discovered that a race condition exists when executing concurrent `MERGE` statements. Specifically, duplicate nodes can be created in the scenario where a node is created after the `MATCH` step but before the `CREATE` step of a given `MERGE`.

This can be worked around in some instances using unique constraints on the merged nodes; however, this falls short in scenarios where:

1. There is no single unique property to enforce (e.g. pairs of properties need to be unique but individual ones don't).
2. Trying to merge relationships and paths.

Does using `CREATE UNIQUE` solve this problem (or do the same pitfalls exist)? If so, is it the only option? It feels like the usefulness of `MERGE` is fairly heavily diminished when it effectively can't guarantee the uniqueness of the path or node being merged...

Comment: According to the answer to [this Grokbase question](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/137q6a6rg5/are-merge-operations-in-cypher-atomic), `MERGE` is supposed to be atomic as of the final release of neo4j 2.0. If you are detecting non-atomic behavior, you should [create a neo4j issue](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/neo4j/137q6a6rg5/are-merge-operations-in-cypher-atomic).

Comment: [This is the correct link](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues) for creating an issue. I just checked, and [this existing issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/5091) might be for the same problem.

Comment: For compound properties you can use an unique constraint on an array prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `MERGE` statements are executed concurrently, these situations may occur. Basically, each transaction gets a view of the graph at the first point of reading, and won't see updates made after that point (with some variations). The main exception to this are uniquely constrained nodes, where Neo4j will initialise a fresh reader from the index when reading, regardless of what was previously read in the transaction.

A workaround could be to create a 'dummy' property and a unique constraint on it and one of the node labels. In Neo4j 2.2.5, this should work to get around your problem.